# How do Action class constructors work with Struts2?

Tags: java, constructor, struts2

I am directly forwarded to a method within my action class (by struts.xml) but I do not actually create a new instance of my Action Class. I ask because I have some variables to set before anything can be done with the ActionClass, and I thought constructors might help me do just that.

Comment: Object will be initialized (by calling constructor) before any of its instance method is executed. So you can write initialization code in constructor.

Comment: So I do not HAVE to create an object of the action class? The constructor will run the first time the class is called upon?

Comment: @user1073616 You want to use those variables in your method?

Comment: Not initially. I have a form that I want to populate on window load based on the current logged in user. The user can then edit the fields and update, at which point the variables are used in the methods

Comment: @user1073616: S2 has a build in factory which is responsible for creating an instance of the action

Comment: @user1073616 no you do not create a action class object, the framework does that for you.  The action object is created on _every_ action invocation, so no not only the first time it is called.

Answer (score 4):

Struts 2 provides a Prepare Interceptor to prepare your data before the actual execute method runs.This interceptor calls prepare() on actions which implement Preparable.
Some of the use cases for using the prepare method in your action class are

1. Loading an object from the database so that when parameters are set they can be set on this object.
2. Preparing/init any data which is needed before the actual method call.

In short this interceptor is like an init/constructor for the Action class and you have all control to initialize any required parameters or do any initial lookup.

For details refer to the interceptor page
[prepare-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/prepare-interceptor.html)